# Warning message while using python request package

Tags: python, python-requests

I am referring python request (v2.9.1) in my python scripts.Am getiing a warning

message in the output console like below.

```
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ndg_httpsclient-0.4.0-py3.4.egg\ndg\httpsclient\subj_alt_name.py:22: 
  UserWarning: Error importing pyasn1, subjectAltName check for SSL peer verification will be disabled.  Import error is: No module named 'pyasn1'
  warnings.warn(import_error_msg)
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ndg_httpsclient-0.4.0-py3.4.egg\ndg\httpsclient\ssl_peer_verification.py:25: 
  UserWarning: SubjectAltName support is disabled - check pyasn1 package installation to enable
  warnings.warn(SUBJ_ALT_NAME_SUPPORT_MSG)
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ndg_httpsclient-0.4.0-py3.4.egg\ndg\httpsclient\subj_alt_name.py:22: 
  UserWarning: Error importing pyasn1, subjectAltName check for SSL peer verification will be disabled.  Import error is: No module named 'pyasn1'
  warnings.warn(import_error_msg)
```

And i have a similar script which I wrote one year back and that also using the same request module and which doesn't have this issue.
Could anyone faced the same issue while using the request module?
Is it because of dependency of request package to some other packages?

Thanks in advance 
Susmitha

Comment: The warning says `pyasn1` isn't installed.  Is that your question?

Comment: Hi Brendan Abel, Thanks for your reply.I installed "pyasn1_modules-0.0.8-py3.4" and still am getting the same